# Open links in new window

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

I have this jQuery script which opens a link in a new window:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.externalUrl', function () {
        window.open(this.href);
    });
```

And in my template I got this snippet of code:

```
{{#Facebook}}
  <a href="{{Facebook}}" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
{{/Facebook}}
```

The problem is, is that it's always opening with localhost in the `url`, in stead of going directly to facebook.com.

Example:

```
http://localhost:57391/www.facebook.com
```

Comment: usually means the original link is `facebook.com` and not `http://facebook.com`

Comment: `href="//{{Facebook}}"` to handle both protocols http or https

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `"http://{{Facebook}}"` or `"https://{{Facebook}}"` for `href` attribute

Answer (score 1):

Add `http://` before the `www`. It should work.

```
{{#Facebook}}
    <a href="http://{{Facebook}}" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
{{/Facebook}}
```

Without it, there's not way the browser know if you want a folder called `www` or an external link.

Here some documentation about absolute and relative URL : http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/htmlweb.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention the protocol also, so that it will be behave as an absolute url.

```
{{#Facebook}}
  <a href="http://{{Facebook}}" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
{{/Facebook}}
```